# Using rabbitmq with twisted

Tags: python, rabbitmq, twisted

I am developing a tcp/ip server whose purpose is receive packets from client, parse them, do some computation(on data arriving in packet) and store it in database. Till now, everything was being done by single server application written using twisted python. Now I am across RabbitMQ so my question is, if it is possible and if it will lead to better performance if my twisted server application just receives the packets from clients and pass it another c++ application using RabbitMQ. The c++ application will in turn parse packets, do computation on it etc.. Everything will be done on single server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server is does not receive packets often, it will not improve much - only gain some tiny overhead on inter server communication. Still it is a very good design idea, because it scales well and once you finally get many packets you will just add an instance of data processing server.

Comment: each client will be sending packets at a interval of 10-12 seconds and initially their will be around 500 clients which will increase later on

Comment: There is no formula for calculating whether it is little or much (anyway, time of data processing on server would have to be counted in), but since the number of clients will increase, I would advise you to seperate the data processing server.

Comment: It won't actually "scale" any better if the poster's comment that "Everything will be done on single server." is accurate.

Comment: Why not? That single server probably has a modern processor capable of running processes really in parallel. If the data processing is just some calculations, the data processing servers can be run totally independently.